# The reason behind Big Bang

Tags: universe, formation, big-bang-theory, early-universe

It always amuse us to research about things around us and we always start our research with a question that - what must be the reason for happening of that phenomenon?

As we know that the formation of universe is being postulated with theory of Big Bang. 
But now, I want to ask that **what was the reason for Big Bang**. I mean **why it happened, what must be the circumstances or what made it happened?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**WHY** implies a **reason**, which is venturing in to the religious realm.

The circumstances under which an event such as the Big Bang occurs are guess work at best. Since the Big Bang is a singularity from which time itself started there is no real *before* the big bang. That's the first problem. The second is that because of the spatial singular nature of the big bang no information from 'before' it could ever pass through to our current universe and provide us with any hints.

There are a number of oddball theories that explore the idea of physics before the big bang. [Some](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9802057v2.pdf) investigate what occurs on scales of time shorter than that of the Planck time, where quantum mechanical processes may give us hints in to the cause or mechanics of a big bang event. Proving or, indeed, disproving these theories is currently impossible experimentally.

Comment: Hey @Chris Lovell I must ask you to watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3MWRvLndzs) after reading your answer. You have tokened singularity, but many still say that there was space existing before Big Bang.

Comment: This video is really great! It explains the themes really well. Unfortunately I disagree with the narrators dismissal of the Big Bang singularity description. A [singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_singularity) is defined as a 'point at which a given mathematical object is undefined'. Since all of our current models of the universe break down at the big bang it is, for all intents and purposes, a singularity. I mentioned that there are other theories that attempt to explain physics beyond this point, however they are not currently mainstream.

Comment: But then the question arises why singularity? Is it mean that when something achieves singularity it must proceed to Big Bang?.....Pls correct me n elaborate urself @Chris.

Comment: The video you linked to explains why 'Big Bang' is a misnomer. A singularity is not a necessary and sufficient description of the Big Bang. Black holes contain gravitational singularities, where general relativity breaks down. If you wish to know more about some of the other theories that explore breaking the singular nature of the big bang you would be best to look at current research papers in the quantum domain. However the mathematics can sometimes be a bit opaque. Good luck! I hope I have at least started you on the right path to answer some of your questions

Comment: thnx @Chris for your ultimate guidance.....and still I would like to be in your touch.